# Multi-monitor screenshot - positioning mouse cursor

Tags: delphi, cursor, position

I have a procedure which takes a screenshot of a monitor and optionally includes the mouse cursor in the snapshot. The original function was only for one monitor. When drawing the mouse cursor, it currently shows properly only on the Main Monitor. But, I can't figure out how to position it on any other monitor. See the comments towards the end of this procedure.

```
procedure ScreenShot(var Bitmap: TBitmap; const MonitorNum: Integer;
  const DrawCursor: Boolean; const Quality: TPixelFormat);
var
  DC: HDC;
  C: TCanvas;
  R: TRect;
  CursorInfo: TCursorInfo;
  Icon: TIcon;
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  M: TMonitor;
  CP: TPoint;
begin
  M:= Screen.Monitors[MonitorNum];
  DC:= GetDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  try
    C:= TCanvas.Create;
    try
      C.Handle:= DC;
      R:= M.BoundsRect;
      Bitmap.Width:= R.Width;
      Bitmap.Height:= R.Height;
      Bitmap.PixelFormat:= Quality;
      Bitmap.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0,0,R.Width,R.Height), C, R);
    finally
      C.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow, DC);
  end;
  if DrawCursor then begin
    R:= Bitmap.Canvas.ClipRect;
    Icon:= TIcon.Create;
    try
      CursorInfo.cbSize:= SizeOf(CursorInfo);
      if GetCursorInfo(CursorInfo) then
      if CursorInfo.Flags = CURSOR_SHOWING then
      begin
        Icon.Handle:= CopyIcon(CursorInfo.hCursor);
        if GetIconInfo(Icon.Handle, IconInfo) then
        begin
          CP:= CursorInfo.ptScreenPos;

          //Transition mouse position...?
          CP.X:= CP.X + M.Left;
          CP.Y:= CP.Y + M.Top;  //No difference?

          Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(
            CP.X - Integer(IconInfo.xHotspot) - R.Left,
            CP.Y - Integer(IconInfo.yHotspot) - R.Top,
            Icon);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Icon.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How do I transition the mouse position properly depending on which monitor I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mapping screen coord `MonitorRect.Left` to bitmap coord `0`. And likewise, `MonitorRect.Top` to `0`. So, if the cursor's screen position is `CursorPos` then you map that to `CursorPos.X - MonitorRect.Left` and `CursorPos.Y - MonitorRect.Top`. And then you also need to account for the hot spot, but you already seem to know how to do that.

The mapping above applies equally to all monitors.

Note that I used my own notation because I found your single letter variables mis-leading. Not to mention that fact that the meaning of these variables changes during the function. I'm look at you, `R`. That's always a recipe for pain.

Also, don't you need to delete the bitmap handles that are handed to you when you call `GetIconInfo`? And some error checking wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Ahh well shoot, the `+` was supposed to be a `-` that did it. And it doesn't work if you remove those 2 lines - it makes the cursor only show if the cursor is on the main monitor, but not the actual monitor the screenshot is of.

Comment: Oh, I see, you used R twice! The value of `R` is the bitmap rect which is always anchored at 0,0.

Comment: Well it was worth recycling, since the beginning of `if DrawCursor then begin` marks the start of a different block of code. Hence the reason I left it a short name such as `R`.

Comment: @Jerry Having variables that aren't named, and take different meanings at different times makes it harder to read the code. That's my advice to you. Take it or leave it.