# Screenshot not show mouse cursor when is moved to second monitor

Tags: delphi, winapi, screenshot, multiple-monitors, delphi-10.3-rio

I have been doing a lot of work lately with taking screenshots (for a remote desktop system) and just stumbled across a problem while I'm trying to implement support for multiple monitors. While taking the screenshot is OK, the method I'm using to draw the cursor only presumes 1 screen. If I position the pointer on an additional screen (when taking a screenshot of that additional screen), the cursor does NOT show. I move the pointer to the main screen and it shows (of course in the wrong spot because it's the wrong screen).

My code is entirely below.

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  vcl.Graphics,
  SysUtils;

function GetCursorInfo2: TCursorInfo;
var
  hWindow: HWND;
  pt: TPoint;
  dwThreadID, dwCurrentThreadID: DWORD;
begin
  Result.hCursor := 0;
  ZeroMemory(@Result, SizeOf(Result));
  if GetCursorPos(pt) then
  begin
    Result.ptScreenPos := pt;
    hWindow := WindowFromPoint(pt);
    if IsWindow(hWindow) then
    begin
      dwThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, nil);
      dwCurrentThreadID := GetCurrentThreadId;
      if (dwCurrentThreadID <> dwThreadID) then
      begin
        if AttachThreadInput(dwCurrentThreadID, dwThreadID, True) then
        begin
          Result.hCursor := GetCursor;
          AttachThreadInput(dwCurrentThreadID, dwThreadID, False);
        end;
      end
      else
        Result.hCursor := GetCursor;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TakeScreenshot(var Bmp: TBitmap; WndHdc: HDC; Width, Height, Left, Top: Integer);
const
  CAPTUREBLT = $40000000;
var
  DesktopCanvas: TCanvas;
  MyCursor: TIcon;
  CursorInfo: TCursorInfo;
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  DC: HDC;
begin
  DC := GetDC(WndHdc);
  try
    if (DC = 0) then
      Exit;
    Bmp.Width := Width;
    Bmp.Height := Height;
    DesktopCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
    try
      DesktopCanvas.Handle := DC;
      BitBlt(Bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, DesktopCanvas.Handle, Left, Top, SRCCOPY or CAPTUREBLT);
      MyCursor := TIcon.Create;
      try
        CursorInfo := GetCursorInfo2;
        if CursorInfo.hCursor <> 0 then
        begin
          MyCursor.Handle := CursorInfo.hCursor;
          GetIconInfo(CursorInfo.hCursor, IconInfo);
          Bmp.Canvas.Draw(CursorInfo.ptScreenPos.X - IconInfo.xHotspot, CursorInfo.ptScreenPos.Y - IconInfo.yHotspot, MyCursor);
        end;
      finally
        MyCursor.ReleaseHandle;
        MyCursor.Free;
      end;
    finally
      DesktopCanvas.Free;
    end;
  finally
    if (DC <> 0) then
      ReleaseDC(0, DC);
  end;
end;

function EnumDisplayMonitors(dc: HDC; rect: PRect; EnumProc: pointer; lData: Integer): Boolean; stdcall; external user32 name 'EnumDisplayMonitors';

type
  TMonInfo = record
    h: THandle;
    DC: HDC;
    R: TRect;
  end;

var
  MonList: array of TMonInfo;

function MonitorEnumProc(hMonitor: THandle; hdcMonitor: HDC; lprcMonitor: DWORD; dwData: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  I, Width, Height, Left, Top: Integer;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  I := High(MonList) + 1;
  SetLength(MonList, I + 1);
  MonList[I].h := hMonitor;
  MonList[I].DC := hdcMonitor;
  MonList[I].R := PRect(lprcMonitor)^;

  Left := PRect(lprcMonitor)^.Left;
  Top := PRect(lprcMonitor)^.Top;
  Width := PRect(lprcMonitor)^.Width;
  Height := PRect(lprcMonitor)^.Height;

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    TakeScreenshot(Bmp, hdcMonitor, Width, Height, Left, Top);
    Bmp.SaveToFile('C:\Screen' + IntToStr(I + 1) + '.bmp');
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure Main;
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Writeln('Number of monitors: ' + IntToStr(High(MonList) + 1) + #13#10);
  Writeln('-----------------');
  for I := 0 to High(MonList) do
    with MonList[I] do
    begin
      S := #13#10 + 'Handle: ' + IntToStr(h) + #13#10 + 'Dc: ' + IntToStr(DC) + #13#10 + 'Size: ' + IntToStr(R.Right) + 'x' + IntToStr(R.Bottom) + #13#10;
      Writeln(S);
      Writeln('-----------------');
    end;
end;

begin
  try
    EnumDisplayMonitors(0, nil, Addr(MonitorEnumProc), 0);
    Main;
    Writeln(#13#10 + 'Connected: ' + IntToStr(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS)) + #13#10);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: So the *real* issue is calculating the screenshot-relative mouse cursor position?

Comment: Determine the correct X/Y position of the pointer according to which monitor is currently interacting.

Comment: So then, ask *that* question. There's no reason why we would need to sift through your code taking a screenshot. It's clearly not related to the issue.

Comment: Simply i need make mouse pointer appear on screenshot when he be on second monitor,

Comment: You would have to get the cursor's screen position, map it into your BMP's coordinate space, and then actually draw the cursor manually. Look at `GetCursorPos()`, or better `GetCursorInfo()` which gives you both the `HCURSOR` handle and its screen position in a single call, rather than using `GetIconInfo()`. To actually draw a `HCURSOR` onto your BMP, you can use `DrawIcon/Ex()` for that

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you, i'll try understand this [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886862/multi-monitor-screenshot-positioning-mouse-cursor) and also your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the cursor coordinates you get from `GetCursorInfo2` are not the correct coordinates relative to your Bitmap.
First, determine whether the cursor point is in the `lprcMonitor`, you ccould use [`PtInRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-ptinrect), and then use [`DrawIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawicon) to draw the hcursor into the bitmap, if it returns true.
Here is an C++ sample convert from your code(since I am not familiar with delphi):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")
int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
        return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;  // Failure
}

//HCURSOR GetCursorInfo2(POINT * pt)
//{
//    POINT p = { 0 };
//    HWND hWindow = NULL;
//    HCURSOR hCursor = NULL;
//    if (GetCursorPos(&p))
//    {
//        pt->x = p.x;
//        pt->y = p.y;
//        hWindow = WindowFromPoint(*pt);
//        if (IsWindow(hWindow))
//        {
//            DWORD dwThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, NULL);
//            DWORD dwCurrentThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
//            if (dwCurrentThreadID != dwThreadID)
//            {
//                if (AttachThreadInput(dwCurrentThreadID, dwThreadID, TRUE))
//                {
//                    hCursor = GetCursor();
//                    AttachThreadInput(dwCurrentThreadID, dwThreadID, FALSE);
//                }
//            }
//        }
//    }
//    return hCursor;
//}
void TakeScreenshot(HDC hdcbmp, HDC WndHdc, int Width, int Height, int Left, int Top)
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (hdc == 0) exit(-1);
    BitBlt(hdcbmp, 0, 0, Width, Height, hdc, Left, Top, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
    CURSORINFO cursorinfo = { 0 };
    cursorinfo.cbSize = sizeof(CURSORINFO);
    if (GetCursorInfo(&cursorinfo))
    {
        RECT rc = { Left ,Top,Left + Width ,Top + Height };

        if (PtInRect(&rc, cursorinfo.ptScreenPos))
        {
            DrawIcon(hdcbmp, cursorinfo.ptScreenPos.x - Left, cursorinfo.ptScreenPos.y - Top, cursorinfo.hCursor);
        }
    }
    /*ICONINFO IconInfo = { 0 };
    GetIconInfo(hCursor, &IconInfo);*/
}
BOOL CALLBACK Monitorenumproc(HMONITOR  hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    static int count = 0;
    int Left = lprcMonitor->left;
    int Top = lprcMonitor->top;
    int Width = lprcMonitor->right - lprcMonitor->left;
    int Height = lprcMonitor->bottom - lprcMonitor->top;

    HDC dev = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC CaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dev);
   
    HBITMAP CaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dev, Width, Height);
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(CaptureDC, CaptureBitmap);
    TakeScreenshot(CaptureDC, dev, Width, Height, Left, Top);
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(CaptureBitmap, NULL);
    
    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/bmp", &pngClsid);
    wstring BmpNameString = L"C:\\screen";
    BmpNameString = BmpNameString + std::to_wstring(count) + L".bmp";
    count++;
    bitmap.Save(BmpNameString.c_str(), &pngClsid, NULL);

    SelectObject(CaptureDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(CaptureDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dev);
    DeleteObject(CaptureBitmap);
    return TRUE;
}
int main(void)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    EnumDisplayMonitors(0, NULL, Monitorenumproc, 0);

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

And attention to these lines in function `TakeScreenshot`:

```cpp
CURSORINFO cursorinfo = { 0 };
cursorinfo.cbSize = sizeof(CURSORINFO);
if (GetCursorInfo(&cursorinfo))
{
    RECT rc = { Left ,Top,Left + Width ,Top + Height };

    if (PtInRect(&rc, cursorinfo.ptScreenPos))
    {
        DrawIcon(hdcbmp, cursorinfo.ptScreenPos.x - Left, cursorinfo.ptScreenPos.y - Top, cursorinfo.hCursor);
    }
}
```